# Compiling win_ros with msvc2010 x64

Tags: ros, compile, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
So i found myself in the situation where i need to compile win_ros in x64.
And it seems that i've made some progress and succeeded in that task. I will try to outline the main steps i took.

1. I installed 64 bit version of Python2.7.5 and then went down the list of packages given here:

[www.ros.org/wiki/win_python_build_tools/groovy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_python_build_tools/groovy)

and installed 64 bit version where possible. In many of those packages i had to manually specify the Python installation directory because it couldn't find it in the registry. The only package i skipped was PySvn but that didn't seem to matter.

After that i compiled dependencies from sources in msvc2010 for x64:

boost 1.47

bzip2 1.0.6

log4cxx 0.10.0

tinyxml 2.6.2 (get it from sourceforge)
tinyxml gave me some trouble trouble down the road so i had to go back and recompile it with /MD(Multi-threaded DLL) flag in C++/Code Generation and also make sure you add TIXML_USE_STL to Preprocessor Definitions

eigen3 (i just copied what i found in include folder in rospeds\groovy\x86)

i put all the compiled dependencies c:/rosdeps/groovy/x86 and added c:/rosdeps/groovy/x86/bin and c:/rosdeps/groovy/x86/lib $PATH. I copied c:/rosdeps/groovy/x86/shared from deps provided for x86 compilation. I also copied Boost.cmake and Boost-debug.cmake to c:/rosdeps/groovy/x86/lib (also taken from x86 deps). I had to modify Boost-debug.cmake to make sure that the names of the boost libraries correspond to the names of newly compiled boost libraries.

then i followed the same procedure for compiling win_ros:

[www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/groovy/Msvc%20Compiled%20SDK](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/groovy/Msvc%20Compiled%20SDK)

I've made changes to setup.bat in ws folder to use msvc2010x64 toolset:

```
@call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
```

And i think that's it. I hope i'm not forgetting anything. I will try to compile win_ros in Debug and also will try to compile it with msvc2012.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69958/compiling-win_ros-with-msvc2010-x64/) by [Eugene Simine](https://answers.ros.org/users/4860/eugene-simine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you join us on the https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/win-ros mailing list? Can be alot more interactive there and I'd love to hear how you go and possibly integrate this properly into win_ros.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0